# How to save file on SD card by using download manger in Android?

Tags: android

I am facing tow issues in my app.

1- I am using Android `DownloadManager` to download online files but it downloads all files to system directories say `Download` directory by using

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "fileName");
```

Now I want to download the file to my own directory say "New Folder". How is it possible to implement. Please help me in this respect, I would be very thankful.

2- How can I check that whether SD card is available or not?

Answer (score 3):

[DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)

1)

```
Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(DOWNLOAD_FILE);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
            request.setDescription("Downloading a file");
            long id =  downloadManager.enqueue(request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                    .setTitle("File Downloading...")
                    .setDescription("Image File Download")
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "cm.png"));
```

2)

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

if(isSDPresent)
{
  // yes download code
}
else
{
 // No sdcard 
}
```